# Error targeting .NET framework 3.0

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have an application, which I develop in VS 2008 and I target .NET 3.

Unfortunately when I install on a clean computer with .NET 3, it crashes. And besides the usual TypeInitilisationError, I have no clue why.

Updating the same machine to .NET 3.5SP1 makes it run fine.

1. Is there something broken in VS2008 that prevents from telling me a more detailed error?
2. How can I be sure I don't use any of the newest classes of the framework?
   It is true that I found myself using DropShadowEffect which belongs to 3SP1. I removed it.

But still...it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the event viewer for more info - there is not much to go on here

Comment: I rolled back the title. This is not about installing .NET, it is about VS targeting a particular framework, but it not running under that framework.

Comment: @Rob: "Unfortunately when I install on a clean computer with .NET 3, it crashes." -- I guess I could be wrong, but he needs to be clear.

Comment: @Rich - My rollback was only to the title, there were no changes by you to the body.

Comment: @Rob: I am not saying it was you, but a tons of changes were lost all the same. Also, the original title made no sense, so just rolling it back seems silly anyway.

Comment: @Rich: The changes were only lost because you and another person were editing at the same time which was unfortunate. More a bug in SO than anything else ;)

Comment: @Rob: Nope, the other editor actually went in and manually reverted nonsensical parts of the post. Some people object to helping people formulate good questions I guess. As I said, I didn't mean to imply you did it.

Comment: Seems people are more interested in editing this than answering ;) I am curious as to why his program that targets 3.0 doesn't run on 3.0 though. It could be something we should watch out for. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: @Rob: I suspect it is because he /wasn't/ actually targeting 3.0.

Comment: @Rob: Also, thanks, you caught more of my lost edits than I had even noticed.

Comment: @Rich: Looks to me like the other editor hit the edit link before you submitted, therefore he was editing the old text when he submitted, effectively negating your edits. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Rob: Doesn't matter really, thanks for the help, question looks good now. Teamwork is fantastic.

Comment: i'm targeting 3. I don't want to make people download 25OMB for features i don't use

Comment: I think it might be that he was targeting 3.0, but that 3.0SP1 was on the dev machine. I forget what was released when though. I am just curious if there are breaking changes in the SP.

Comment: I am not finding a 3.0 SP1 and he said 3.5 SP1.

Comment: The OP keeps asking what he is using in the new framework that might be causing the issue. My bet is still on an assembly is being compiled for 3.5

Comment: .Net 3.0 and 3.0 sp1 come as standalone installs from Mircorosft, and when you install .Net 3.5 sp1 you automatically get upgraded to .Net 3.0 sp2

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to determine which version of the framework is installed on each computer. If you're using .Net 3.5 SP1 to compile the program it actually includes .Net 3.0 sp2 which has some extra features (MultiSelector class to name one) which are not available in .Net 3.0 sp1 which is the default install with .Net 3.0 download from Microsoft.

You can try here for some software that will help:
[NetVersionCheck](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/11/06/how-to-check-what-version-of-microsoft-net-framework-is-installed-in-computer/)

**EDIT:**
Visual Studio won't tell you about any errors for this because everything seems fine with the version of .Net 3.0 that it's using. I ran into this problem using the WPF toolkit as it requires the MultiSelector class which didn't arrive until .Net 3.0 sp2. So, Jonathan, if you can show us the error output from your program on the 'Fresh' .Net 3.0 computer then we could probably tell you what you're using that is in .Net 3.0 sp2 that isn't supported in lower versions.

Also, I usually use VS2005 with programs that I want to run under a lower runtime than .Net 3.5sp1, but this really only applies to .Net 2.0 apps.

If we knew what components from .Net 3.0 that you're using, it would help as well!

Answer (score 0):

Noah

Thanks for the answer.
Because of VS2008, on my dev computer i have the latest 3.5SP1.
But in Visual Studio i selected 3 as a target.

And to check i install on a clean computer with 3.0...

So your proposition do tells me which framework is installed, but does not tell me what in my program uses in the newest framework that is not present in 3.0.

Moreover, something must be broken in VS2008 as it should warm me for that...

Comment: This is not an answer, either edit your question or leave a comment please.

Comment: I think that Noah is correct. Your project is targeting .NET 3.0. On your machine, .NET 3.0 includes .NET 3.0 SP2, which includes components that were added after the original release. VS can't tell the difference, because it can only go by what is on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is a problem with VS 2008, but obviously MS feels differently.

VS 2008 comes with .NET 3.5, some .NET 3.0 service pack, and .NET 2.0 SP1.  It can only detect whether you are using things that don't belong to a version that is *installed on your machine*, not whether you are conforming to some service pack.  This means that if you target .NET 2.0, but install your software on a machine that does not have .NET 2.0 SP1, if you use anything specific to SP1 your application will fail when it tries to make the call.

The only way to detect this that I have seen is to inspect the changelist of the service packs or to target .NET 3.5.  If .NET 3.5 is installed, so are the service packs that come with it.  It's not a good solution, but it's the only one I've found.